# Error - Constructor parametrizado fallido

Tags: java

Soy nuevo en Java. Estoy intentando realizar intentando replicar el siguiente diagrama UML en Java:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede apreciar se trata de una asociación unidireccional de composición, con la clase `Team` como clase compuesta y la clase `StatisticsTeam` como componente, de tal forma que si desaparece `Team` también desaparece el objeto `StatisticsTeam` vinculado.
Los métodos/setters/getters y requerimientos son los siguientes:

- El constructor debe inicializar todos los atributos con el valor por defecto indicado en el diagrama UML.
  **- Al crear un objeto de tipo `Team` se tiene que crear un objeto `StatisticsTeam` que le corresponda.**
- Siempre que exista conflicto entre nombres, sobretodo en los métodos setter, se tiene que usar la palabra reservada `this`.
- Si el nombre que se asigna al equipo tiene más de 50 carácteres, entonces hay que lanzar `Exception`.
- Si el NIF que se quiere asignar al equipo no cumple con el patrón establecido, entonces setNif no tiene que asignar ese valor al equipo y en su lugar lanzar una Exception. El patrón es: nombre que empiece por A, B o G en mayúsculas seguido de 8 dígitos.
- El mail que se quiere asignar al equipo tiene que contener una @ y acabar en .es o com.
  **- El método `resetStatistics()` tiene que instanciar un nuevo objeto `StatisticsTeam`.**
- El valor de la capacidad tiene que ser superior a 0.
- El método `getInfo` tiene que devolver un texto con el siguiente formato: Name: N - Foundation year: Y - NIF: F. Siendo N el nombre del equipo; Y el año de fundación; F el NIF.

He codificado la clase `Team` de la siguiente manera:

```
package edu.uoc.pac3;

public class Team {
    private int id;
    private static int nextId = 0;
    private String name;
    private String foundationYear;
    private String nif;
    private String email;
    private int capacity;
    private StatisticsTeam statistics;

    public Team() throws Exception {
        this.setId();
        this.setName("Lorem club");
        this.setFoundationYear("2000");
        this.setNif("G12345678");
        this.setEmail("info@yourmail.com");
        this.setCapacity(21);
        this.getStatisticsTeam();
    }

    public Team(String name, String foundationYear, String nif, String email, int capacity) throws Exception {
        this.setId();
        this.setName(name);
        this.setFoundationYear(foundationYear);
        this.setNif(nif);
        this.setEmail(email);
        this.setCapacity(capacity);
        this.getStatisticsTeam();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    private void setId() {
        this.id = getNextId();
        this.incNextId();
    }

    public static int getNextId() {
        return nextId;
    }

    private void incNextId() {
        ++nextId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) throws Exception {
        if (name.length() > 50) {
            throw new Exception("[ERROR] Team's name cannot be longer than 50 characters");
        } else {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public String getNif() {
        return this.nif;
    }

    public void setNif(String nif) throws Exception {
        String pattern;
        pattern = "^[ABC]\\d{8}";
        if (nif.matches(pattern)){
            this.nif = nif;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("[ERROR] Team's NIF pattern is incorrect");
        }
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) throws Exception {
        String pattern1 = "^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]+\\.es$";
        String pattern2 = "^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]+\\.com$";
        if (email.matches(pattern1) || email.matches(pattern2)) {
            this.email = email;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("[ERROR] Team's email pattern is incorrect");
        }
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return this.capacity;
    }

    public void setCapacity(int capacity) throws Exception{
        if (capacity <= 0) {
            throw new Exception("[ERROR Team's capacity must be greater than 0]");
        } else {
            this.capacity = capacity;
        }
    }

    public String getFoundationYear() {
        return this.foundationYear;
    }

    public void setFoundationYear(String foundationYear) {
        this.foundationYear = foundationYear;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        String text;
        text = "Name:" + this.name + "- Foundation year:" + this.foundationYear + "- NIF:" + this.nif ;
        return text;
    }

    public StatisticsTeam getStatisticsTeam() {
    return statistics;
}

public void resetStatistics() {
    this.statistics = new StatisticsTeam();
   }
}
```

Para comprobar que se está haciendo bien, se han realizado los siguientes test:

```
package edu.uoc.pac3;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance.Lifecycle;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
class IntegrationTest {

    Team team;

    @BeforeAll
    void init() {
        try{
            Field field = Team.class.getDeclaredField("nextId");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(null, 0);
            team = new Team("Futbol Club Barcelona", "1899", "G08266298", "sac@fcbarcelona.com", 25);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            fail("Parameterized constructor failed");
        }
    }

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    void testTeamDefault() {
        try{
            Team t = new Team();
            assertEquals(1, t.getId());
            assertEquals("Lorem club", t.getName());
            assertEquals("2000", t.getFoundationYear());
            assertEquals("G12345678", t.getNif());
            assertEquals("info@yourmail.com", t.getEmail());
            assertEquals(21, t.getCapacity());
            assertNotNull(t.getStatisticsTeam());
            assertEquals(0, team.getStatisticsTeam().getWon());
            assertEquals(0, team.getStatisticsTeam().getDrawn());
            assertEquals(0, team.getStatisticsTeam().getLost());
            assertEquals(0, team.getStatisticsTeam().getGoalsFor());
            assertEquals(0, team.getStatisticsTeam().getGoalsAgainst());
            assertEquals(0, team.getStatisticsTeam().getGamesPlayed());
            assertEquals(0, team.getStatisticsTeam().getGoalsDifference());
            assertEquals(0, team.getStatisticsTeam().getPoints());
        }catch(Exception e) {
            fail("Default constructor failed");
        }
    }}
```

Sin embargo, algo estoy haciendo mal porqué devuelvo `Parametrized constructor failed`, es decir la `Exception` del `void init()` salta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que puedas realizar la prueba y evites el mensaje de error `Parametrized constructor failed` :

```
try{
    Team t = new Team();
    assertEquals(1, t.getId());
    assertEquals("Lorem club", t.getName());
    assertEquals("2000", t.getFoundationYear());
    assertEquals("G12345678", t.getNif());
    assertEquals("info@yourmail.com", t.getEmail());
    assertEquals(21, t.getCapacity());
    assertNotNull(t.getStatisticsTeam());
    assertEquals(0, team.getStatisticsTeam().getWon());
    assertEquals(0, team.getStatisticsTeam().getDrawn());
    assertEquals(0, team.getStatisticsTeam().getLost());
    assertEquals(0, team.getStatisticsTeam().getGoalsFor());
    assertEquals(0, team.getStatisticsTeam().getGoalsAgainst());
    assertEquals(0, team.getStatisticsTeam().getGamesPlayed());
    assertEquals(0, team.getStatisticsTeam().getGoalsDifference());
    assertEquals(0, team.getStatisticsTeam().getPoints());
}catch(Exception e) {
    fail("Default constructor failed");
}
```

No es necesario que declares el constructor vacio en tu clase `Team` o si lo deseas declarar serìa de esta forma:

```
public class Team {
    private int id;
    private static int nextId = 0;
    private String name;
    private String foundationYear;
    private String nif;
    private String email;
    private int capacity;
    private StatisticsTeam statistics;

    public Team()  {         
    }

    public Team(String name, String foundationYear, String nif, String email, int capacity) throws Exception {
        this.setId();
        this.setName(name);
        this.setFoundationYear(foundationYear);
        this.setNif(nif);
        this.setEmail(email);
        this.setCapacity(capacity);
        this.getStatisticsTeam();
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }
```

Ya que la prueba consiste en instanciar la clase y asignarle paràmetros:

```
Team t = new Team();
```

> Siempre que exista conflicto entre nombres, sobretodo en los métodos
> setter, se tiene que usar la palabra reservada this.

Si, tienes que usar this para hacer referencia a la propiedad de la clase tanto para para asignar el valor como para obtenerlo

```
public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
}
```

Si el nombre que se asigna al equipo tiene más de 50 carácteres, entonces hay que lanzar Exception, esto es correcto.

```
public void setName(String name) throws Exception {
    if (name.length() > 50) {
        throw new Exception("[ERROR] Team's name cannot be longer than 50 characters");
    } else {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

al parecer todos los demàs puntos son correctos solo corrige el constructor.

Comment: Genial! Lo que no entiendo ahora es porqué me está dando error en el assertNotNull(t.getStatisticsTeam());.

Comment: Ya está, incluí statistics = new StatisticsTeam();

Answer (score 0):

Esto no puede ser así:

```
public Team() throws Exception {
    this.setId();
    this.setName("Lorem club");
    this.setFoundationYear("2000");
    this.setNif("G12345678");
    this.setEmail("info@yourmail.com");
    this.setCapacity(21);
    this.getStatisticsTeam();
}
```

Cuando creas un constructor vacío no puedes meterle nada dentro

```
public Team(){
}
```

Por ello con este cambio cuando vayas a hacer `Team t = new Team();` debería funcionarte bien ya que ahora si estás instanciando bien el objeto

Comment: Si quito los setters como comentas sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Como que en un constructor vacío no puedes meter nada dentro??? Lo que no se debe hacer es tirar excepciones en el constructor, pero ... meter lógica en él?  En cuanto al mensaje de error que te da, estás obfuscando el error real, imprimiendo un mensaje que no te ayuda en nada a la hora de ver qué está pasando, @Panri93. Quita el string hardcodeado y en vez de eso imprime el mensaje de la excepción, además del stacktrace, verás qué error real te está dando el constructor